# MissingMemberException when using CallByName

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

After setting up my model using the Entity Framework 6 Database First wizard, and creating a DbContext:

```
    Dim db As New mydatabaseEntities
```

then using LINQ with one of my database tables: `db.stations` (type:`DbSet(Of station)`) shown below, the query works as expected:

```
    Dim myDbSet1 = db.stations
    Dim isQuerable1 = TypeOf myDbSet1 Is IQueryable
    Dim query1 = myDbSet1.Where(Function(record) record.id = "677010")
```

However, if I specify the database table name as a string, and then use `CallByName` to get the `DBSet(Of station)` at run-time, I get an error:

```
    Dim tableName As String = "stations"
    Dim myDbSet2 = CallByName(db, tableName, CallType.Get)
    Dim isQueryable = TypeOf myDbSet2 Is IQueryable
    Dim query2 = myDbSet2.Where(Function(record) record.id = "677010")
```

In both cases, `myDbSet1` and `myDbSet2` have the `IQueryable` interface. But, in the second example, I get the following error:

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Where' on type 'DbSet(Of station)' not found.'
```

- Why are some of the interface methods missing in the second example?
- Will I have similar problems any time I use `CallByName`, or is the problem related either to interfaces, or to LINQ/Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Where` is an Extension method on the IEnumerable(Of T) interface and by inheritance for the [IQueryable(Of Out T) interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx).  The method does not really exist on the object.  Its call is wired up by the compiler.

Depending on what your usage case is, either of the following should work.  Just remember to null test `myDbSet2` in case the cast fails.

```
Dim myDbSet2 = TryCast(CallByName(db, tableName, CallType.Get), IEnumerable(Of Station))
```

or

```
Dim myDbSet2 = TryCast(CallByName(db, tableName, CallType.Get), IQueryable(Of Station))
```

Comment: This works (thank you!), but I'm still confused: I was previously evaluating `TypeOf myDbSet2 Is IQueryable` and getting the result `True`.  `myDbSet2` already had the `IQueryable` interface but not the extension methods?

Comment: @isedwards, do you fully understand what "Extension Methods" are and how they work?  If not, please read through [Articles about Extension Methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2007/01/24/articles-about-extension-methods/).  Pay particular attention to [Extension Methods Part 4: Extension methods and late binding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2007/01/24/articles-about-extension-methods/).   If you are still confused, I'll attempt to explain it further.

Comment: those links were extremely useful (plus they've also given me a sense of where it may make sense to write my own Extension Methods)